# Adding values on 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have created a program that lets the user input the number of rows and columns they want in a 2d array and then it fills the array with all even numbers starting from 0.

I have to add all the numbers in the array to get a total sum and I have no idea how to do that. The rest of my program is complete I'm just having trouble with the sum.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class ArrayOver { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many rows? ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many columns? ");
        int y = scan.nextInt();

        int[][] nums = new int[x][y];
        fillArray(nums);
        displayArray(nums);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void fillArray(int nums[][]) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < nums.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < nums[0].length ; col++) {
                nums[row][col] = count;
                count++;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void displayArray(int nums[][]){
        for (int row = 0; row < nums.length; row++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums[row]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix the indentations. I, for one, will not look at the code in the current state.

Comment: Could you add your sum code? It should be pretty much the same algorithm as fillArray but this time you have sum instead of count; `sum += nums[row][col]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void countArray(int[][] nums)
{
  int total=0;

  for (int row=0;row<nums.length;row++)
    for (int col=0;col<nums[0].length;col++)
      total += nums[row][col];

  System.out.println(total);
}
```

This should go through all the numbers in the array and add their values to total.

Comment: Oh, you've fixed the indentation now. (You hadn't when I started writing) Yay!

Answer (score 0):

If you want sum all elements of array, just do it:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < nums.length ; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < nums[row].length ; col++) {
       sum = sum + nums[row][col];
   }
}
```